# Constructor mediante String

Tags: java, constructor, split

Tengo que hacer un constructor en la clase `CancionImpl` que recibe una cadena con los valores de las propiedades separadas por punto y coma (;), en el siguiente orden: id de tipo `String`, artista de tipo Artista, duración en segundos, nombre de tipo `String`, popularidad de tipo `Integer`. No sé cómo obtener artista ni la duración.

```
public CancionImpl(String s) {
    String[] trozos = s.split(";");
    ...
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Si usas split, obtendrás un array de elementos.

```
String[] trozos = s.split(";");
```

los elementos los puedes obtener por su indice iniciando en 0

```
0 - id de tipo String
1 - artista de tipo Artista, NO se puede obtener un tipo artista ya que los elementos son de tipo String.
2 - duración en segundos
3 - nombre de tipo String
4 - popularidad de tipo Integer.
```

de esta forma, para convertir a entero puedes usar `Integer.paserInt()`:

```
String id = trozos[0];
String artista = trozos[1];
String duracion = trozos[2];
String nombre = trozos[3];
int popularidad = Integer.paserInt(trozos[4]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Para Artista, manda sólo el atributo String que tenga el valor que deseas, en lugar de mandar el objeto entero.

Para duración, solo tendrías que convertir de String a Integer... Integer duracionInteger = Integer.parseInt(duracionstring)

Answer (score 0):

En principio yo lo veo bien te faltaría un for para poder sacar los valores del array de trozos.

```
for(int i = 0; i< trozos.length; i++)
System.out.println(trozos[i]);
}
```

Una vez tengas la lista puedes parsear los valores a tu antojo siempre y cuando todas las strings que recibas tengan el mismo orden